# Flutter plugin async and thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, dart, flutter

I have a flutter app that calls into a Java plugin using methodchannel.

I'm trying to understand the thread model and async behavior. So the order is like this... 
     A UI event handler calls await methodchannel.invoke("Foo", params). Which transfer control to the Java method call handler. There I reply.success to unblock the await in dart. The await returns and flutter UI event handler returns.

In the Java plugin I continue to the some more work after result.sucess. Say for another 2seconds.

The problem is (my question) during that 2 seconds, the dart main thread/UI is blocked, even though the flutter event handler had returned 2 seconds ago? Why is that? I can see from my logcat that dart and Java code are running in two separate threads. Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm skeptical of the problem you're describing. What you have described is true, and all Dart code is async, and Dart and Java run all different thread, thus except if Dart is doing something CPU-heavy, it should not block main thread/UI.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are doing something weird, if this is really happening. Also, don't return a fake `success`. The callbacks are all asynchronous, and are meant to provide real results.. if you don't want your dart code to "block" just don't `await` .. you can handle the result using future's `then` callback, or `await` in another isolate.

Comment: post your java code: most likely you are somehow blocking the UI main thread there

Comment: I haven't done anything with plugins myself yet, but `await` itself does *not* block the UI, it only delays the execution of the code below `await` from being executed until the returned `Future` completes. Other async code can still be called (from timers, or animation triggers, or other code invoked by the framework for example depending on screen refresh rate. I don't know though if calling out to Java can block the UI thread.

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22024) - the native code runs on the native UI thread, so you shouldn't block it or you risk stalling input and other platform specific issue. The solution is to do your additional 2 seconds of work on a separate thread. (The creator of the above issue argues that you should be able to do work on the main thread, but not many people seem to agree...) The point is there's an easy work around - background thread. I thought I saw a really good diagram of the 3 main threads the other day, but now I can't find it again.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was surprised by this behavior. But as @RichardHeap mentioned in his comment, this is by design. Platform plugin thread is same as the UI thread. So don't block it.  So can someone explain what are the two threads: one running flutter/dart and one running the java code?

Comment: there are no two threads: there is only one main UI thread, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: logcat message shows two threads 3880 & 3884                                                                                                              
 2019-03-11 13:12:15.743 3804-3880/com.essential.camera I/flutter: CameraPresenter _controllerEventHandler exit
2019-03-11 13:12:15.743 3804-3804/com.essential.camera D/essentialcam_CameraPlugin: onMethodCall takePicture enter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter by default can process single-threaded tasks, but this doesn't mean that it'll stop the main thread just to wait for the `Future` task. Concurrent tasks can be run utilizing Future callbacks that can execute a command when the task is complete, like when using `Future.then()`.

If you'd like to dig deeper, here's a well-written article covering [Future async tasks in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/futures-async-await-threading-in-flutter-baeeab1c1fe3).